# Behavior changes from computer to computer despite the exact same source code

Tags: ros2

I am having trouble running the exact same ros2 code on two computers with the following specs, with different behavior.

```
Computer 1:
  CPU: Intel 12th Gen Core i7-12700TE
  Memory: 16GB
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04
  ROS2: humble
  GPU: RTX A4000 SFF Ada

Computer 2:
  CPU: Intel 9th Gen Core i7-9700E
  Memory: 16GB
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04
  ROS2: humble
  GPU: Nothing
```

1. Node A publishes data of type A to Topic A. QoS uses SensorDataQoS, which is provided by default in ros.

```
a_pub = create_publisher<TypeA>("topic_a", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS());
...
a_pub->publish(msg_a);
```

2. Node B is subscribing to Topic A, which processes the data into type B and flows it to Topic B. The QoS is SensorDataQoS() for both.

```
b_sub = create_subscription<TypeA>("topic_a", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(), std::bind(callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
b_pub = create_publisher<TypeB>("topic_b", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS());
...
void callback() {
  ...
  b_pub->publish(msg_b);
}
```

3. When each node is started in this state, the callback of Node B is called extremely infrequently, even though the logs confirm that Node A’s publish is successfully looped.
   Node A publishes at approximately 10 Hz, but Node B’s callback is extremely low, such as 0.7 Hz.
4. For the QoS of Node A’s publisher and Node B’s subscriber, if the reliability is changed from best_effort (SensorDataQos is best_effort) to reliable, data flows instantly.
   However, even though the callback of Node B is normally called and processed at 10 Hz, the msg of topic_b is only about 3 Hz. (The callback process itself completes instantly.)
5. The above is happening with the Computer 1, but if exactly the same source code is run on the Computer 2, topic_b flows at 10 Hz without any problems.

Are there any possible causes?

Comment: there is a cause for everything ... perhaps the question could be worded differently